# How to get value of components from Fragment which are linked with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

> I am trying to get values of components which are there inside fragment and fragments are dynamically added to ViewPager

```
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
            EditReviewPageAdapter editReviewPageAdapter = (EditReviewPageAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();

            for(int i=0;i<editReviewPageAdapter.getCount();i++)
            {
                EditReviewFragment editReviewFragment = (EditReviewFragment) editReviewPageAdapter.getItem(i);

               // editReviewFragment.getValue(i);

                Fragment fragment = editReviewPageAdapter.getItem(i);
                if(fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvReviewTitle)!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Title Available");
                }

            }
```

> > I am getting *java.lang.NullPointerException* near if condition

Comment: try this `fragment.getView().....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep mind that the ViewPager only loads a maximum of 3 fragments at a time by default.

If you want to get value inputs from the individual fragments I suggest adding a Bundle to the parent Activity/Fragment, and add values to the same parent bundle from each ViewPager fragment.

Then in the end you have a fully populated bundle that you can inspect for values.